# PHP doesn't executes both if clauses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpseclib

On my page, you have a on and off button to start a ssh command on the server. The on button works just fine, but when I press the off button, the PHP server kind of just skips the if clause, while my POST variable is set to false.

JS

```
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
    b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
    b1.onclick = function () {
        $.post("conJava.php", {
            statusServer: "aan"
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        console.log("aan");
    };
    b2.onclick = function () {
        $.post("conJava.php", {
            statusServer: "uit"
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        console.log("uit");
    };
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/phpseclib1.0.7');
include('phpseclib1.0.7/Net/SSH2.php');

$status = $_POST['statusServer'];
echo $status;
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ,22);

if (!$ssh->login('pi', 'appieh4ck')) {
   exit('Login Failed');
} else{
  if ($status == "aan"){
    $ssh->exec('pkill java');
    echo "Java server is succesvol gestopt!";
  }

  if ($status == "uit"){
    $ssh->exec('pkill java');
    $ssh->exec('java -jar jserver.jar');
    echo "Java server is succesvol gestart!";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your buttons do the oposite?In your Example `aan` kills the server and `uit` starts it

Comment: Yeah, I now see my mistake too, so stupid. It works now, thanks!